# Working with a non-standard date time format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a system that auto-populates a mysql database with data.  Unfortunately the the only time value is being stored in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.SSS.  Have a script that runs against the data in the database in a 30 minute cron to alert on certain data trends.   The problem that I'm having is that the data in the database goes back 7 days.  I only want the script to run against the past 30 minutes of data.

I tried using something like:

```
SELECT foo FROM table WHERE StartTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTES);
```

Unfortunately this didn't work, I'm assuming because the stored time formation does not match a standard SQL Timestamp format.

Can anyone suggest an alternate method?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you running on cron? Is it a shell script?

Comment: What about generating the timestring for "30 minutes ago" and comparing with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartTime >=  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s.000')`